# Select Distinct Based on a Min of another column SQL

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, odbc

I have 3 columns of data I wish to select from, see sample below

```
WONO    EQMFSN      DOCDT8
8523248 02T300118   20160616
8523248 02T300118   20160621
8523248 02T300118   20160620
8523249 02T300118   20160620
8523249 02T300118   20160620
2414888 02T300118   20161109
2414888 02T300118   20161109
2414888 02T300118   20161109
2414888 02T300118   20161109
1127111 02T300118   20170321
8523253 02T300119   20160620
8523253 02T300119   20160625
8523253 02T300119   20160624
8523254 02T300119   20160624
8523254 02T300119   20160624
2414893 02T300119   20161113
2414893 02T300119   20161113
2414893 02T300119   20161113
2414893 02T300119   20161113
1127116 02T300119   20170325
```

I want to select the distinct EQMFSN and WONO, for the MIN DOCDT8

So my output would be:

```
EQMFSN      WONO
02T300118   8523248
02T300119   8523253
```

I have tried:

```
Select  
    T.EQMFSN
,   min( T.docdt8)
,   T.wono

From
    T

Group By
    T.EQMFSN
,   T.wono
```

By data is in IBM DB2, but i am creating this query via an odbc/as400 connection in Excel.

Comment: Your desired results and problem description do not match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated the sample, i quickly threw the sample together in excel, my bad

Comment: Desired output still does not make sense.  There is only one minimum DOCDT8.

Comment: @paparazzo Each EQMFSN has a minumum DOCDT8, i want the WONO that matches the Min, and the EQMFSN

Comment: Still does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your desired output, you meant to ask for min of each of the EQMFSN fields:

You ideally should try to get min DOCDT8 for each EQMFSN by grouping on it and then join it back to the original table to get corresponding WONO.
This should match

```
SELECT EQMFSN, WONO
FROM t
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT EQMFSN, min(DOCDT8) as mindoc from t group by EQMFSN) t2
on t2.EQMFSN = t.EQMFSN
and t2.mindoc = t.DOCDT8;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to our problem:

```
SELECT `EQMFSN`,`WONO`
FROM TAble1
WHERE `DOCDT8` IN (
                   SELECT MIN(`DOCDT8`)
                   FROM TAble1
                   GROUP BY `EQMFSN`
                  )
GROUP BY `EQMFSN`
```

**Output:**

```
EQMFSN      WONO
02T300118   8523248
02T300119   8523253
```

The demo for your query:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31437d/6

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you would seem to want:

```
select distinct EQMFSN, WONO
from t
where t.date = (select min(t2.DOCDT8) from t t2);
```

The only caveat is that this would return:

```
EQMFSN      WONO
02T300118   8523248
```

Because the minimum date is `'20160616'` and there is only one record on that date.